# Unable to parse sub items using JSON

Tags: java, android, json, stringbuilder, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing formatting my json correctly and I was wondering if someone could show how to parse the data correctly in this instance:

### SOURCE:

```
  try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()){
                sb.append(line);
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String sha = obj.getString("sha");
                String name = obj.getString("name");
                String message = obj.getString("message");
                Log.d("sha", sha);
                Log.d("name", name);
                Log.d("message", message);

            }
        }
```

### ERROR:

"No value for name"

### JSON DATA:

http://pastebin.com/0FJUGm3L

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29. you can use `obj.getJSONObject("commit");`

Comment: start debugging the code and see from where it breaks :) It will help you lot I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your JSON into this [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) tool, you will recognize that you have the following JSON structure:

[image]

Now, since you want to get `sha, commit message, and commiter name`, you will need to go deep into json's object structure.

1. First, you will need to loop the entire json array:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject currentObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   ```
2. Inside the loop, you need to find where the "sha" is. Take a look at the structure again and you'll notice it is right under the object. So you just need to use [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29):

   ```
   String sha = currentObj.getString("sha");
   ```
3. To get commit `message`, since it is under `commit` object, you will need to read that object first, before reading `message`:

   ```
   JSONObject objCommit = currentObj.getJSONObject("commit");
   String commitMessage = objCommit.getString("message");
   ```
4. The final piece is to get author's `name`. Again, notice that `name` is stored under `author` object. So, you will need to read that first. And because `author` object is stored under `commit` object, you get author by reading commit object via `objCommit`:

   ```
   JSONObject objAuthor = objCommit.getJSONObject("author");
   String authorName = objAuthor.getString("name");
   ```
5. The rest is up to you :)

Selfless plug: Also, if you are having a hard time reading or traversing JSON, the SO question can come in handy: [JSON Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321595/json-parsing-error/7884112#7884112)

Answer (score 0):

All keys name,message,.. is in `author` JSONObject. gett all values from `author` object as:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String sha = obj.getString("sha");
                // get commit  object
                JSONObject objcommit = obj.getJSONObject("commit"); 
                // get author  object
                JSONObject objauthor = objcommit.getJSONObject("author");
                String name = objauthor.getString("name");
                String message = objauthor.getString("message");
                Log.d("sha", sha);
                Log.d("name", name);
                Log.d("message", message);

            }
```